# EF include with where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've Resource and ResourceDetail. 
MemberPoint with memberId and ResourceId.

I would like to get Resources Details for a member.

In SQL,

```
Select d.* From ResourceDetails d Inner Join 
        Resource on r d.ResourceId = r.Id Inner Join 
        MemberPoint mp on r.id = mp.ResourceId 
        where mp.memberId = 1
```

In EF,

```
   var query = _context.ResourceDetails
            .Include(d => d.Resource)
            .Include(r => r.Resource.Memberpoints)
            .Where(e => e.Resource.Memberpoints.Where(m => m.MemberId))
```

I got error when I write above EF query.

Error: unknown method 'Where(?)'of System.Linq.IQueryable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using include this way:

```
var query = _context.MemberPoint.Include("Resource.ResourceDetails")
                                .Where(m => m.MemberId == 111111);
```

Or try joining on resourceId and selecting an anonymous type with the data you need:

```
var query = (from m in _context.MemberPoint
            join rd in _context.ResourceDetails on m.ResourceId equals rd.ResourceId
            where m.MemberId == 11111
            select new
            {
               Member = m,
               ResourceDetail = rd
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using EF completely incorrectly.

What you want is actually

If ResourceDetails has one Resource and each reasource has one member (unlikely).

```
var query = _context.ResourceDetails
        .Include(d => d.Resource)
        .Include(r => r.Resource.Memberpoints)
        .Where(d => d.Resource.Memberpoints.MemberId == 1);
```

If ResourceDetails has one Resource and each resource can have multiple Members.

```
var query = _context.ResourceDetails
        .Include(d => d.Resource)
        .Include(r => r.Resource.Memberpoints)
        .Where(d => d.Resource.Memberpoints.Any(m => m.MemberId == 1));
```

If ResourceDetails has multiple Resources (unlikely) and each resource can have multiple Members.

```
var query = _context.ResourceDetails
        .Include(d => d.Resource)
        .Include(r => r.Resource.Memberpoints)
        .Where(d => d.Resource.Any(r => r.Memberpoints.Any(m => m.MemberId == 1)));
```

Okay. So what about the join you wanted? Well that is the job of the ORM. The ORM mapping already knows how `ResourceDetails` are linked to `Members`.

So what was that error you got?

Well, the sig of `IQueryable.Where()` takes a `Func<T, bool>` and returns an `IQueryable<T>`.

So in your example, the inner `Where` is wrong because you are giving it a `Func<T, int>`. The outter `Where` is wrong because you are passing a `IQueryable<T>` to it (although the compiler doesn't know that because its all sorts of wrong already).

TL:DR

In general, don't join with EntityFramework/Linq. EF should have the associations in the mappings and already knows how to join entities together.

Comment: Hi Aron, I would like to filter by memberid. kindly explain how to add Memberpoints.MemberId == 1 in EF.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MemberId is unique as per your query example. Try this

```
  var query = _context.ResourceDetails
        .Include(d => d.Resource)
        .Include(r => r.Resource.Memberpoints)
        .Where(e => e.ResourceId == e.Resource.Memberpoints.Where(m => m.MemberId == 1))
```

Comment: It will if MemberPoint.MemberId is unique. But I'll delete my answer if stated by OP