# Return from database not all data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, code-first

```
 using (var db = new ConnectToDB())
        {
            var matches = db.Matches;
            var matchesToReturn = new List<SimpleMatch>();
            foreach (var item in matches)
            {
                var match = new SimpleMatch();
                match.Id = item.Id;
                match.Home = item.Home.Name;
                match.Guest = item.Guest.Name;
                match.HomeTeamGoals = item.Result.HomeTeamGoals;
                match.GuestTeamGoals = item.Result.GuestTeamGoals;

                matchesToReturn.Add(match);

            }

            return matchesToReturn;
        }
```

all item has id and DateMatch, but item.Home, item.Guest, item.Result ==null

[img return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcpZK.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy Loading vs Eager Loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366236/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading)

Comment: Probably these fields are empty in your database?

Comment: fields filled, can't return data from another table what have relationship with table `Matches`

Comment: Lazy Loading disabled

Comment: You need to include relative tables of Matches using [Include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698969/ef-include-with-where-clause) syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure to load the related objects. For example like this:

```
foreach (var item in matches.Include(x => x.Home).Include(x => x.Guest).Include(x => x.Result))
{
    ...
}
```